# Implementing two-factor authentication into a Java web app

Tags: java, security, authentication

I have an existing Java web application running through IBM WebSphere (I'm unsure of the version, but could find out if it helps) that I am looking to implement two factor authentication with.

The system has a decent user base, and I wanted to distribute hardware tokens to the admin users of the system to ensure strong authentication.

Minimal impact to the end user is desirable, but I'd like to avoid having the admins need to go through a VPN connection.

Does anyone know of any products that provide Java APIs that could be directly integrated into the existing application or other products that will provide a minimal impact?  I've already spoken with RSA SecurID, but their system wouldn't integrate directly and would require an infrastructure change.  Any other ideas/experience is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For posterity, I've just posted my simple [Java two factor authentication utility class to Github](https://github.com/j256/java-two-factor-auth).  With it, you can do something like the following:

```
TwoFactorAuthUtil twoFactorAuthUtil = new TwoFactorAuthUtil();

// To generate a secret use:
// String base32Secret = generateBase32Secret();
String base32Secret = "NY4A5CPJZ46LXZCP";
// now we can store this in the database associated with the account

// this is the name of the key which can be displayed by the authenticator program
String keyId = "user@j256.com";
System.out.println("Image url = " + twoFactorAuthUtil.qrImageUrl(keyId, base32Secret));
// we can display this image to the user to let them load it into their auth program

// we can use the code here and compare it against user input
String code = twoFactorAuthUtil.generateCurrentNumber(base32Secret);

// this little loop is here to show how the number changes over time
while (true) {
    long diff = TwoFactorAuthUtil.TIME_STEP_SECONDS
        - ((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) % TwoFactorAuthUtil.TIME_STEP_SECONDS);
    code = twoFactorAuthUtil.generateCurrentNumber(base32Secret);
    System.out.println("Secret code = " + code + ", change in " + diff + " seconds");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: When I try this, if I have the step seconds at 30, it still steps  & generates a new code at 11 seconds. No matter what value I set for step seconds, the code only stays for around 40-45% of that time and then expires.

Comment: It should generate a new code on the minute and at the 30 seconds after the minute as aligned to your clock.   Does that make more sense @ClickUpvote?

Comment: Hmm, when I set the time to be 30 secs, I expect that to mean the code will last for 30 seconds. That way its more reliable. Otherwise the codes are being expired 10 seconds and 15 secs, which is way too short.

Comment: This is about syncing between the server time and the client-time via the Google authenticator application (or something similar).  There is no way to control the client-time.  You might have 29 seconds until the code expires or 1.  Users understand that already @ClickUpvote.

Answer (score 1):

If you want two-factor authentication via a TLS client-certificate, there are a few hardware cryptographic tokens out there. Java can load a PKCS#11 store out of the box, although some configuration may be required. How much of it is admin configuration vs. application configuration depends on the application (and sometimes on how 'locked' the terminal is w.r.t to inserting a USB token or having a card reader).

There may be alternative solutions, such as One-Time Password tokens (which don't rely on certificates, but on unique passwords instead). This seems less heavy for the users. I must admit I've never tried it, but this project might be interesting: http://directory.apache.org/triplesec/ (There are also hardware OTP keyrings, usually by the same vendors who do RSA cards/USB tokens).

Comment: I was just looking at a question on IT SE re Apache triplesec! I noticed some odd things about it. Should I ask as a question there? Or is its apparent lack of status i.e. 404'd, already well-known as of 2013, might you know? I always hesitate about seeming like an idiot, even though they are extremely kind-hearted on IT SE.

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry! I just realized that this was you http://security.stackexchange.com/a/3839/3607

Answer (score 0):

We have API packages for Java (and php, ruby, python, and C#): http://www.wikidsystems.com/downloads/network-clients for the WiKID Strong Authentication system.  These packages are LGPL, so you can also use them in commercial products.  They work with both our open-source community version and the commercial Enterprise version.

HTH,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use Spring Security we have a plugin which offers two factor authentication (physical and soft tokens) - [www.cloudseal.com](http://www.cloudseal.com)